# Wrapping c++ class so I can use it in c#

Tags: c#, c++, clr, pinvoke

I have this c++ header:

```cpp
// BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere.hxx file
#include <Standard.hxx>
#include <Standard_DefineAlloc.hxx>
#include <BRepPrim_Sphere.hxx>
#include <BRepPrimAPI_MakeOneAxis.hxx>

class gp_Pnt;
class gp_Ax2;

class BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere : public BRepPrimAPI_MakeOneAxis
{
public:
    DEFINE_STANDARD_ALLOC

    Standard_EXPORT BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere(const Standard_Real R);
    Standard_EXPORT Standard_Address OneAxis();
    Standard_EXPORT BRepPrim_Sphere& Sphere();

protected:


private:
    BRepPrim_Sphere mySphere;
};
```

and this c++ source:

```cpp
// BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere.cxx file
#include <BRepBuilderAPI.hxx>
#include <BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere.hxx>
#include <gp.hxx>
#include <gp_Ax2.hxx>
#include <gp_Dir.hxx>
#include <gp_Pnt.hxx>

BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere::BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere(const Standard_Real R) :
       mySphere(gp::XOY(),R)
{
}

Standard_Address  BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere::OneAxis()
{
  return &mySphere;
}

BRepPrim_Sphere&  BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere::Sphere()
{
  return mySphere;
}
```

Standard_EXPORT is defined as follows:

```cpp
# define Standard_EXPORT __declspec( dllexport )
```

DEFINE_STANDARD_ALLOC is defined as follows:

```cpp
# define DEFINE_STANDARD_ALLOC  
void* operator new (size_t theSize)                                  
  {                                                                    
    return Standard::Allocate (theSize);                               
  }                                                                    
void  operator delete (void* theAddress)                             
  {                                                                    
    Standard::Free (theAddress);
  }
void* operator new[] (size_t theSize)                               
  {                                                                   
    return Standard::Allocate (theSize);                              
  }                                                                   
void  operator delete[] (void* theAddress)                          
  {                                                                   
    Standard::Free (theAddress);
  }
void* operator new (size_t, void* theAddress)                       
  {                                                                   
    return theAddress;                                                
  }                                                                   
void operator delete (void*, void*)                                 
  {                                                                   
  }
```

I want to use them in my c# code.

I have tried three methods that didn't work for me:

1. Wrapping the c++ code with CLR to manage it and then use it in the c# code.
2. SWIG
3. P/Invoke

Now the issue is that this is one class in a huge c++ library. What I am trying to do is automatically generate the warppers for every single class so I can have the library's full functionality.

The main problem I'm having is handling return types and arguments.

This is what I'm trying right now:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Call_BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere(BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere* p, const Standard_Real R) {
    p->BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere::BRepPrimAPI_MakeSphere(R);
}
```

But I obviously can't use this in c# because the two argument types don't exist in c# right?

Basically my question is how and what would be the best way to wrap this class?

Comment: You can write a COM layer, relatively small, that exposes your internal class hierarchy into a COM objects hierarchy. That's how many Windows API are built. For example of a nice COM objects hierarchy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-2-0-interfaces Once you have that, it's pretty easy to use from .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Basically my question is how and what would be the best way to wrap this class?

I would use c++/cli, that should let you define .Net wrappers that can interact directly with native c++ objects.

> What I am trying to do is automatically generate the warppers for every single class so I can have the library's full functionality.

I do not think this can be done in general, at least not without extra knowledge about resource management and other details not expressed in the c++ source. Just consider if a C# object is disposed, should you delete the underlying C++ object? To decide this you need to know if the object is shared or not, and there is no general way to know this.

But creating and using c++/cli code is kind of a pain. You need to have a fair bit of in depth knowledge of c#, c++ and c++/cli. In some cases there are just no alternative, but I would consider other solutions first, like .Net native libraries, or rewriting the required functions in C#.